# How to prove $\frac{5abc+1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1\right)+6\ge \sum_{\text{cyc}}\sqrt{5a^3+4}$ when $a^2+b^2+c^2=a+b+c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

**Question**

Let $a,b,c>0: a^2+b^2+c^2=a+b+c.$ Prove that $$\color{black}{\frac{5abc+1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1\right)+6\ge \sqrt{5a^3+4}+\sqrt{5b^3+4}+\sqrt{5c^3+4}}.$$
I've tried to eliminate the radical by Cauchy-Schwarz$$\frac{5abc+1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1\right)+6\ge \sqrt{3}.\sqrt{5(a^3+b^3+c^3)+12}$$
But the rest is not easy to me. I am waiting some ideas and proofs.

Thanks for your help.

> **Updated editings:**
> Until now, we recieved two proof by hand verified by Mathematica.
> Is there a simpler proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative proof.**

By given condition, we can rewrite the OP as $$(ab+bc+ca)\left(5+\frac{1}{abc}\right)-5abc+23\ge 4\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{5a^3+4}.$$ Or $$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}\left[5(a^2+b^2+c^2)+\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{abc}\right]-5abc+23\ge 4\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{5a^3+4},$$ $$\iff\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\left[\left(5a^2+\dfrac{a}{bc}\right)(ab+bc+ca)-5a^2bc+7a+8b+8c\right]}\ge 4(a+b+c)\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{5a^3+4}.$$ Now, base on symmetrical principle we should try to prove $$\left(5a^2+\frac{a}{bc}\right)(ab+bc+ca)-5a^2bc+7a+8b+8c\ge 4(a+b+c)\sqrt{5a^3+4}. \tag{*}$$
Can you end it now ?

---

Indeed, the $(*)$ is equivalent to $$\left(5a^2+\dfrac{a}{bc}\right).\frac{a(b+c)}{a+b+c}+8\ge4\sqrt{5a^3+4}.$$ Notice that by AM-GM $$\frac{a(b+c)}{a+b+c}=\frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{a}+\dfrac{1}{b+c}}\ge \frac{2}{\dfrac{2}{a}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}}.$$
Hence, it is enough to prove$$\frac{5a^2+\dfrac{a}{bc}}{\dfrac{2}{a}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}}+4\ge2\sqrt{5a^3+4}.$$
Dividing both side by $a,$ we will prove $$ \frac{\dfrac{1}{bc}+5a}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{2}{a}}+\dfrac{4}{a}\ge2\sqrt{5a+\dfrac{4}{a^2}}.$$
The last inequality is true by AM-GM$$ \frac{\dfrac{1}{bc}+5a}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{2}{a}}+\dfrac{4}{a}= \frac{5a+\dfrac{4}{a^2}}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{2}{a}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}+\dfrac{2}{a}\ge2\sqrt{5a+\dfrac{4}{a^2}}.$$
The proof is done. Equality holds at $a=b=c=1.$

Comment: -1, Did you squaring both side $(*)$ ? I think it is possible because it is non homogenous inequality.

Comment: Please don't. I hope you can spend time to full it. Id est, I will post it.

Comment: @Dragonboy I added somthing. See now

Comment: It is out of my reach. A beautiful solution!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Use a better bound.

---

**Some thoughts**.

We have, for all $x \ge 0$,
$$\sqrt{5x^3 + 4} \le \frac{13}{8}x^2 - \frac34 x + \frac{17}{8}.$$
(*Note*: We have $\mathrm{RHS}^2 - \mathrm{LHS}^2 = \frac{169x^2 - 138x + 33}{64}(x - 1)^2 \ge 0$.)

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{5abc+1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}-1\right)+6
\ge \frac{13}{8}(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) - \frac34 (a + b + c) + \frac{51}{8}. \tag{1}$$
This inequality is true which can be proved by the pqr method. But my proof is not nice.

Comment: +1, could you please explain "Pade approximation." ?

Comment: @TATAbox You can search Pade approximation. Or see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713384/which-is-greater-frac1332-or-ln-left-frac32-right/3714060#3714060)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Nice, I accept it

Comment: @TATAbox By the way, in your nice [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4746965/prove-2xyyzzx3-ge-sqrt5x24-sqrt5y24-sqrt5z24-when-x-y-z0/4747007#4747007), we may alternatively use the rational bounds there (you used AM-GM). (Already upvote about two days ago.)

Comment: @RiverLi It's interesting

Comment: Why did you remove previous proof by Pade approximation?

Comment: @TATAbox Because I found a simpler bound. You see a quadratic function bound which makes the expression much shorter.

Comment: Yes, I know your means but I think you should add it as alternative proof, a long with your previous one. They are helpful ideas.

Comment: @TATAbox I always want to find a better proof if any. Also, using rational bounds is well-known strategy. Anyway, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @RiverLi I have no mean seriously, just I notice that your answer is very good. It might be useful for others.

Comment: @TATAbox Thanks. I think you just take it easy. Here is a place for happy discussion.

Comment: @RiverLi Of course, have an interest to share math!

Comment: I really want to accept your answer @RiverLi. All answer is good TATAbox's one is so magical.

Comment: @Dragonboy Just feel free to accept the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

A sketch of the proof.

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$ and since by AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{5a^3+4}\leq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{5a^3+4}{2a+1}+2a+1\right),$$ it's enough to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where $f$ decreases.

Thus, by $uvw$ it's enough to prove $f(w^3)\geq0$ for equality case of two variables, which after homogenization and assuming $b=c=1$ gives:
$$(a-1)^2\left(2a^{11}+4a^{10}+11a^9-3a^8-12a^7+84a^6+464a^5+684a^4+472a^3+352a^2+32a+96\right)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Can you get a full solution?

Comment: Thanks. How did you come up with such hard AM-GM ?

Comment: @Dragon boy Firstly I tried AM-GM with $a+2$, but it leads to a wrong inequality. But with $2a+1$ it turned out. It's interesting that C-S $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{2a+1}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2(a+b+c)+a+b+c}=\frac{a+b+c}{3}$ leads to a wrong inequality.

Comment: I will try expand and show it as expression of $uvw.$ The condition quite sadism

Comment: @Dragon boy  We know that $v^2=\frac{3u^2-u}{2}$ and after this we can work with $w^3$ and $u$ only.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg +1, very nice AM-GM step

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, +1 for the nice AM-GM.

Comment: Please give me a hint https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748060/a-b-c-ge-0-abbcca-3-find-minimal-and-maximal-p-frac1-sqrtabc7-f